# group_by and apply code to each element in group using conditions

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, aggregate

I have data like so:

```
  ID  membership   AdultChild    
   1     1           A
   2     1           A 
   3     2           A  
   4     2           C  
   5     2           C
   6     3           A 
   7     3           A 
   :     :           :
```

I want to group by membership and apply a 'code' after counting the *AdultChild* variable i.e.

```
ID membership   AdultChild code
 1    1           A          x1
 2    1           A          x1
 3    2           A          x2
 4    2           C          x2
 5    2           C          x2
 6    3           A          x1
 7    3           A          x1
 :    :           :          :
```

I will have conditions similar to:

```
count <- function(x){
if(sum(x == "A") == 2 && sum(x == "C") == 0){
  code <<-  x1
}else if (sum(x == "A") == 1 & sum(x == "C") >= 1){
  code <<- x2
}else {
  code <<- X3
}
```

I have tried using dplyr to group and mutate, using the function above to add a new variable called *code*. I also thought about using the *aggregate* function but didn't have much luck.

```
df.2 <-  df %>% group_by(membership) 
         %>% mutate(n = count(AdultChild)) %>% 
         ungroup()

df.2 <-  aggregate.data.frame(df, by = membership, FUN = 
         count(df$AdultChild))
```

Basically, I want a new variable which be decided using certain conditions and applied to each ID when grouped by membership.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide some sample data using `dput()`

Comment: My data is literally identical to the first example I gave, what more are you looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 count <- function(x){
 if(sum(x == "A", na.rm = T) == 2 & sum(x == "C", na.rm = T) == 0){
  y <-  "4"
} else if (sum(x == "A", na.rm = T) > 2 & sum(x == "C", na.rm = T) == 0){
  y <- "5"
}else if (sum(x == "A", na.rm = T) == 1 & sum(x == "C", na.rm = T) >= 1){
  y <- "6"
}else if (sum(x == "A", na.rm = T) == 2 & sum(x == "C", na.rm = T) <= 3 & sum(x == "C", na.rm = T) >= 1){
  y <- "7"
}else {
  y <- "8"
}
}

df.2 <-  df %>% group_by(membership) %>% mutate(code = count(AdultChild)) %>% ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(membership) %>% 
       mutate(code=case_when(
        sum(AdultChild=='A', na.rm = T)==2 & sum(AdultChild=='C', na.rm = T)==0 ~ 'X1',
        sum(AdultChild=='A', na.rm = T)==1 & sum(AdultChild=='C', na.rm = T)>=1 ~ 'X2',
        TRUE ~ 'X3'
))
 # A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   membership [3]
ID membership AdultChild code 
<int>      <int> <fct>      <chr>
1     1          1 A          X1   
2     2          1 A          X1   
3     3          2 A          X2   
4     4          2 C          X2   
5     5          2 C          X2   
6     6          3 A          X1   
7     7          3 A          X1
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't run. If you see the count function, I only want a code to be applied should a certain condition be satisfied. I have altered the function to add an *else* statement.

Comment: @williamg15 in your function change x1,x2,x3 to 'x1', 'x2', 'x3' and change <<- to <- and it will work. Just becareful with the `&&`

Comment: Is there a way to do it with more than two conditions? case_when() is limited in this respect